# Rewriterule для мультичекбоксов

Tags: checkbox, mod_rewrite, php

Добрый вечер,
правильно ли так делать:
есть php скрипт, который может принимать значения с разных чекбоксов,
в зависимости от числа входящих(или 3 или 2 или 1)дальше уже смотрю,
что выбрал пользователь цену, название, модель или каких-то 2 параметра или все 3.

*понимаю что, что-то тут не то:)потому, что если добавить еще 1набор параметров,
будет много возможных вариантов...*

все сделал через гет(сессий нет)
ссылка строится

```
http_build_query

т.е  category.php?name=1&brand=rus&price=300
```

а может быть

```
category.php?name=1&brand=rus&brand=eng&brand=jap&price=300

 или вообще 1 параметр  category.php?name=1
```

плюс если сюда добавить номера страниц, получается ад

1. Правильно ли я сделал обработчик, верна ли логика
2. Как сделать правильно:)
3. Если так делают(и то что я нагородил - правильно:), то что писать в RewriteRule? для каждого набора параметров строку?
4. или тут невозможно и не нужно  применять mod_rewrite ?
   но получается очень много строк, если еще в урл добавить пару типов переменных

Заранее спасибо=)

Comment: а куда тут rewrite rule запихать ?

Comment: зачем его туда пихать... оно идет в отдельном файле......

Comment: в смысле причем тут rewrite_rule покажите пример что-ли что вы делаете.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+n)/$ /categoty/listCreator.php?name=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+n)\/([0-9]+)$ /categoty/listCreator.php?name=$1&page=$2 [L]
и так писать для каждого количества параметров?
т.е для каждого входящего добавлять правило, или можно для скрипта сделать что-то общее и так как я делаю - неправильно?

Comment: url то какой формируется от браузера ? скорее всего проще будет использовать `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` или `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` , а в rewrite посылать все запросы на адрес /category/listCreator.php (в нём обрабатывать переменные вышеозначенные)

Comment: я принимаю переменные get'ом, потом их фильтрую, если они ок то-
$url=http_build_query($_GET)...из всех переменных
складывается запрос в зависимости от числа переменных

Comment: пример запроса покажите. rewrite это такая штука которая преобразует URI запроса **браузера** в новый URI, причем тут ваши `$url=http_build_query($_GET)` совершенно не понятно.